# I cant use my linux file?

Tags: linux, minecraft

Im trying to install Minecraft and I run the command and it says this:

```
stress@penguin:~$ sudo dpkg -i Minecraft.deb
(Reading database ... 33346 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack Minecraft.deb ...
Unpacking minecraft-launcher (928) over (928) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of minecraft-launcher:
 minecraft-launcher depends on default-jre; however:
  Package default-jre is not installed.
 minecraft-launcher depends on libnspr4 (>= 2:4.9-2~); however:
  Package libnspr4 is not installed.
 minecraft-launcher depends on libnss3 (>= 2:3.22); however:
  Package libnss3 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package minecraft-launcher (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.62) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 minecraft-launcher
stress@penguin:~$
```

(I included the line of code I typed)

Comment: what is your question? ... did you read the printout?

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to install `Minecraft.deb` locally which, as you can tell, has several dependencies. `dpkg` doesn't resolve dependencies and that's why you are getting the errors.

The only way to install it with `dpkg` is to download the `deb` files for all of the dependencies and install them in order. Needless to say, you don't want to engage in such tedium.

To install Minecraft from its `deb` file, use the command, with sudoer rights, `apt install /path/to/Minecraft.deb`. That will let it know that you are installing Minecraft from a local `deb` file so that it doesn't try to get it from the repos while also installing the dependencies themselves from the repos.